# perl extract text between SAME delimiter using flip-flop

Tags: perl, delimiter, flip-flop

I have been able to use flip-flop to extract text in past where I have different START & END.
This time I've been having A LOT of trouble trying to extract text because I do not have different delimiters in my source file, because START & END of flip flop are the same.  I want flip flop to start true when line beings with year yyyy & continue to push `$_` to an array until another line begins yyyy.
The problem with flip-flop is that it will then be false on my next START.

```
while (<SOURCEFILE>) {
  print if (/^2017/ ... /^2017/) 
}
```

Using the above for the given source data will miss the 2nd multi-line part of the file I also need to match.  Maybe flip-flop which I thought was the best way to parse a multi line file will not work in this case?  What I want to do is start matching with the first line starting with date & continue matching until the line before the next line beginning with a date.

Sample Data is:

```
2017 message 1
Text
Text

Text

2017 message 2
more text
more text

more text

2017 message 3
yet more text
yet more text

yet more text
```

But I am getting:

```
2017 message 1
Text
Text

Text

2017 message 2
2017 message 3
yet more text
yet more text

yet more text
```

...missing message 2 contents..

I cannot rely on space or a different END delimiter in my source data.
What I wanted was for each message to be printed (actually `push @myarray, $_` & then test for matches), but here I am missing lines below message 2 because flip flop is set to false.  Any way to handle this with flip-flop or I need to use something else?
Thanks in advance for anyone that can help/advise.

Comment: I had a similar issues with an SQL file full of blocks delimited by the same SQL comment. When I failed to use the flip-flop operator, I eventually read the whole file into a variable with `perl -ne "BEGIN { $/ = undef } ..."` and used multiline-regexes to match the desired blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;
my $part = -1;
my $parts;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^2017/ .. 1==0) {
        $part++ if /^2017/;
        push @{$parts->[$part]}, $_;
    }
}
say Dumper$parts;

__DATA__
2017 message 1
Text
Text

Text

2017 message 2
more text
more text

more text

2017 message 3
yet more text
yet more text

yet more text
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '2017 message 1',
            'Text',
            'Text',
            '',
            'Text',
            ''
          ],
          [
            '2017 message 2',
            'more text',
            'more text',
            '',
            'more text',
            ''
          ],
          [
            '2017 message 3',
            'yet more text',
            'yet more text',
            '',
            'yet more text'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Hmm, well spotted. That `if` line is actually redundant isn't it?

Comment: @Sobrique, It's used to skip the lines before the first one matching `/^2017/`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with flipflop. I tried it before a year. But the same thing i did with some logic.

```
my $line_concat;
my $f = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    if(/^2017/ && !$f) {
        $f = 1;
    }

    if (/^2017/) {
        print "$line_concat\n" if $line_concat ne "";
        $line_concat = "";
    }

    $line_concat .= $_ if $f;
}

print $line_concat if $line_concat ne "";
```

Comment: One more thing... it works, but you're never resetting `$f`. Why not? You could put the reset and a `redo` into the second `if` block to make each pair actually be a pair, but I don't see a benefit in doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Flip flop with a matched delimiter doesn't work too well, as you've found.

Have you considered setting `$/` instead?

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

local $/ = "2017 message";
my $count;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    print "\nStart of block:", ++$count, "\n";

    print;

    print "\nEnd of block:", $count, "\n";
}

__DATA__
2017 message 1
Text
Text

Text

2017 message 2
more text
more text

more text

2017 message 3
yet more text
yet more text

yet more text
```

Although it's not perfect, because it splits the file on the delimiter - meaning there's a 'bit' before the first one (so you get 4 chunks). You can resplice it with judicious use of 'chomp', which removes `$/` from the current chunk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

local $/ = "2017 message";
my $count;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    #remove '2017 message'
    chomp;
    #check for empty (first) block
    next unless /\S/;
    print "\nStart of block:", ++$count, "\n";
    #re add '2017 message'
    print $/;
    print;

    print "\nEnd of block:", $count, "\n";
}
```

Alternatively, how about an array of arrays, that you update the 'target key' each time you hit a message?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper;

my %messages; 
my $message_id;
while ( <DATA> ) {
   chomp;
   if ( m/2017 message (\d+)/ ) { $message_id = $1 }; 
   push @{ $messages{$message_id} }, $_; 
}

print Dumper \%messages;
```

Note - I'm using a hash, not an array, because that's a bit more robust for messages sequencing that doesn't start consecutively from zero. (And array using this approach would have an empty 'zeroth' element).

Note - it also will have 'empty' `''` elements for you blank lines. You can filter these if you wish though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a buffer that accumulates the lines until you find one matching `/^20\d\d[ ]/` or end of file.

```
my $in = 0;
my @buf;
while (<>) {
   if ($in && /^20\d\d[ ]/) {
      process(@buf);
      @buf = ();
      $in = 0;
   }

   push @buf, $_ if $in ||= /^2017[ ]/;
}

process(@buf) if $in;
```

---

We can rearrange the code to make it so the records are only processed in one spot, allowing `process` to be inlined.

```
my $in = 0;
my @buf;
while (1) {
   $_ = <>;

   if ($in && (!defined($_) || /^20\d\d[ ]/)) {
      process(@buf);
      @buf = ();
      $in = 0;
   }

   last if !defined($_);

   push @buf, $_ if $in ||= /^2017[ ]/;
}
```

Comment: The above comments were never correct, and have been rendered obsolete by changes to the answer.